# Swift - HTML stylised NSAttributedString with links

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView and I have a string of HTML I give it like so...

```
func applyHTML() {

    textView.attributedText = htmlString()
    textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: .blue,
                               NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue,
                               NSFontAttributeName:font]

}

func htmlString() -> NSAttributedString? {

    if let htmlData = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding) {

        do {

            let attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData,
                                                                 options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                                 documentAttributes: nil)


            return attributedString


        } 
        catch { return nil }
    }

    return nil
}
```

This works fine, I get blue hyperlinks with black text... what I want to do now is style the font for all and colour of the non-hyperlink text... problem is when I do that, by adding this....

```
let length = attributedString.length
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

attributedString.setAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:.white,NSFontAttributeName: myFont,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
```

it removes the hyperlinks... I want them to work in tandem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `addAttributes()` instead of `setAttributes()`?

Comment: That did it! What a dumb mistake... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who visits, @Larme was right

```
attributedString.setAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:.white,NSFontAttributeName: myFont,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
```

should be

```
attributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:.white,NSFontAttributeName: myFont,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
```